# retrieving data from a file in C

Tags: c, file-io

My program starts by asking if the user would like to import a file, if the user selects yes, then they are asked to give the name of the file they would like to use. I can't seem to get the input from the file to work and display accordingly. Basically I'm trying to take the names and numbers from a file and enter them into the show phonebook portion of my application. As of right now, it just seems to take in the file, but store nothing. Here is the 3 main functions that deal with my issue.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#define BUFFSIZE 500
//Structure for contacts. These are now pointers.
typedef struct friends_contact{

 char *First_Name;
 char *Last_Name;
 char *home;
 char *cell;
}fr;
//Function declarations 
void menu(fr*friends ,int* counter,int i,char buffer[]);
void setFirst(fr*,int *,int i,char buffer[]);
char getFirst(fr*,int i);
void setLast(fr*friends, int* counter, int i,char buffer[]);
char getLast(fr*friends , int i);
void setHome(fr*friends, int* counter, int i,char buffer[]);
char getHome(fr*friends, int i);
void setCell(fr*friends, int* counter, int i,char buffer[]);
char getCell(fr*friends, int i);
void add_contact(fr*friends,int* counter,int i,char buffer[]);
void print_contact(fr*friends ,int* counter, int i,char user_entry3[50]);
char delete_contact(fr*friends ,int* counter, int i);
int show_contact(fr*friends ,int* counter, int i);
void file(fr*friends ,int* counter, int i,char user_entry3[50]);
char file2 (fr*friends ,int* counter, int i,char user_entry3[50]);

int main() {


 fr friends[5];
 char buffer[BUFFSIZE];
 int counter=0;
 int i=0;

 menu(friends, &counter,i,buffer);

getch();
return 0;
}

 void menu(fr*friends,int* counter, int i,char buffer[]) {
   int user_entry=0;
   int user_entry2=0;
   char user_entry3[50]={'\0'};

   printf("Welcome! Would you like to import a file? (1)Yes or (2) No");
   scanf("%d",&user_entry);
      if(user_entry==1)
         {
         printf("please enter the name of the file");
         scanf("%s",user_entry3);  
         file2(friends ,counter, i,user_entry3);        
         }else;
   do{
    int result;

      printf("\nPhone Book Application\n");
      printf("1) Add friend\n2) Delete friend\n3) Show a friend\n4) Show  phonebook\n5)Exit\n");   
     scanf("%d", &user_entry);


       if(user_entry==1)
        {
         add_contact(friends,counter,i,buffer);
        }
       if(user_entry==2)
        {
        delete_contact(friends ,counter,i);
        } 
       if(user_entry==3)
        {
        result=show_contact(friends ,counter,i);
           if(result==0)
               {
                printf("\nName not Found\n");
                }else{
                     result;
                     }

        }                  
       if(user_entry==4)
        {
        print_contact(friends, counter,i,user_entry3);
        } 
 }while(user_entry!=5);
      if(user_entry==5)
       {
       printf("Would you like to save entries to a file? (1)yes or (2) no");
       scanf("%d",&user_entry2);
         if(user_entry2 == 1)
          {
           printf("Please name your file");
           scanf("%s",user_entry3); 
           file(friends, counter,i,user_entry3);
           printf("Goodbye!"); 

       }else if(user_entry2 == 2)
         {
        printf("Goodbye!"); 
    }
  }
```

Here is the function in which I am trying to open the file and retrieve the information.

```
void file2(fr*friends ,int* counter, int i, char user_entry3[50])
 {

  FILE *read;
  read=fopen(user_entry3,"r");
  for( i = 0; i < *counter; i++)
        {
        fscanf(read,"%s",friends[i].First_Name);
        fscanf(read,"%s ",friends[i].Last_Name);
        fscanf(read,"%s",friends[i].home);
        fscanf(read,"%s",friends[i].cell);
        }

  fclose(read);

}
```

And lastly, here is where I attempt at adding the date from the file, to the phonebook.

```
void print_contact(fr*friends ,int* counter, int i,char user_entry3[50]) 
 {

  for( i = 0; i < *counter; i++)
    if (strlen(friends[i].First_Name) && strlen(friends[i].Last_Name)&&strlen(friends[i].home)&& strlen(friends[i].cell ))
      {
        file2(friends,counter,i,user_entry3);
        getFirst(friends, i);
        getLast(friends, i);
        getHome(friends, i);
        getCell(friends, i);

       }
 }
```

My logic might be faulty, but I cant seem to figure this out. I can post the rest of the code if needed, but I'm hoping I am making a simple mistake and someone can catch it by looking at what I have provided.

Answer (score 0):

what value does `counter` have and why are both `counter` and `i` passed as arguments at all?  if `counter` is zero then nothing will be read from the file.

wouldn't it be better to read until the end of the file?  maybe you would then set `counter` (or return a value for it).

there is absolutely no reason for `i` to be a parameter; it should be a local variable.

and if you included a definition of `fr` and a `main` so that the example could be compiled and run you might get more detailed help...

Answer (score 0):

Andrew Cooke is right, you are passing `counter` as 0, so file2 reads nothing, as instructed.   Note that when this is changed to `counter=1`, your program then fails because the structure `fr` is full of pointers not allocated memory.  You were asking about how to allocate the memory in a question a day or two ago, so maybe you should look at that first.

Your code has many other issues but, at least you can fix the structure and stop passing `counter` and `i` into functions.  But then you have the problem of your friends array having a fixed size - you need to avoid overrunning the end...